# Changing "woocommerce_template_loop_product_title" heading tag

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm attempting to change the WooCommerce `woocommerce-loop-product__title` from a `H2` to a `h6` but I'm having some trouble.

I've used the following snippet to unhook the original function and replace it with the `h6`. Unfortunately, this does add the `h6` but it also retains the original `h2`.

Can anybody point out where this is going wrong?

```php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'soChangeProductsTitle', 10 );
function soChangeProductsTitle() {
    echo '<h6 class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</h6>';
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all we are going to apply a `remove_action` to the existing title.
Priority `10` is used for this (which is default in WooCommerce, see attached code line).

Copied/pasted from [/includes/wc-template-hooks.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-hooks.php) line 98 @version 2.1.0

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
```

---

However, the priority number can be different if the theme you use differs from the default behavior in WooCommerce (in short, this is theme dependent)

Then we will overwrite the existing output (that we just removed) with the output we want, based on the existing output. The existing output can be found in the same file I referenced earlier in my answer, namely on line 1165 @version 2.1.0

So you get:

```php
/**
 * Show the product title in the product loop. By default this is an H2.
 */
function action_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title() {
    // Removes a function from a specified action hook.
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
    
    echo '<h6 class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</h6>'; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'action_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 9 );
```

---

**OR** to apply this only to related products (single product page), use:

```php
function action_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title() {
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    // Only for related products
    if ( isset( $woocommerce_loop['name']) && $woocommerce_loop['name'] === 'related' ) {
        // Removes a function from a specified action hook.
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
        
        echo '<h6 class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</h6>'; // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'action_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 9 );
```